# SQL Multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql, join

**I am working on a sql query to do the following:**

For each project, retrieve the project number, the project name, and the  number of employees from department 5 who work on the project.

**So far my query looks like this:**

```
SELECT p.PNO
     , p.PNAME
     , COUNT( DISTINCT w.ESSN) '# employees from Dept. 5'
  FROM project p
  JOIN department d
    ON d.DNO = p.DNO 
  JOIN employee e
    ON e.DNO = d.DNO 
  JOIN works_on w
    ON w.ESSN = e.SSN
 WHERE e.DNO LIKE '5' 
   AND p.PNO LIKE 10
```

**Where I am testing it for project number 10 which should return the number of employees from Dept. 5 as 1, however it returns NULL. I think that I need to somehow join the project and employee tables but I am unsure**

**Attached is my schema**

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI0eM.png)

Comment: Please attach sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your joins are wrong.

You should be joining only projects, works_on and employee tables.

```
SELECT p.PNO, p.PNAME, COUNT( DISTINCT w.ESSN) '# employees from Dept. 5'
FROM project p
INNER JOIN works_on w 
ON p.pno = w.pno
INNER JOIN employee e 
ON w.essn = e.essn
WHERE e.DNO LIKE '5' AND p.PNO LIKE 10
```

And you are missing the group by at the end:

```
GROUP BY p.PNO, p.PNAME
```

Comment: @ Walter_Ritzel Makes much more sense, thanks a lot!